# How can I detect the server-initiated termination of a Keycloak session in a Vue application?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, keycloak

Imagine I have an application like [this one](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-quickstarts/tree/latest/applications/app-vue) ([description](https://www.keycloak.org/securing-apps/vue)).

In this application you can login via Keycloak and see a protected page.

I want to display a message (e. g. a JavaScript alert) whenever the user is logged out by the server.

This can happen in at least the following two cases:

1. Administrator terminates the session in the Keycloak GUI.
2. The "User session limiter" terminates the session when the same user logs in on a different device and the number of maximum allowed sessions of the same user is exceeded (e. g. when only one active session per user is allowed, the user is logged in on device 1, and logs in on device 2).

**How can I detect that the user has been logged out by the server?**

I tried adding `alert("Server-initiated logout");` into the `catch` clause of [main.js](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-quickstarts/blob/latest/applications/app-vue/src/main.js):

```
setInterval(() => {
  keycloak.updateToken(70).then((refreshed) => {
    if (refreshed) {
      Vue.$log.info('Token refreshed' + refreshed);
    } else {
      Vue.$log.warn('Token not refreshed, valid for '
        + Math.round(keycloak.tokenParsed.exp + keycloak.timeSkew - new Date().getTime() / 1000) + ' seconds');
    }
  }).catch(() => {
    alert("Server-initiated logout");
    Vue.$log.error('Failed to refresh token');
  });
}, 6000)
```

But this did not work. The alert appeared even when there was no logout.

**Update 1**

Added the code

```
keycloak.onAuthSuccess = function() {
console.log('onAuthSuccess');
}

keycloak.onAuthRefreshError = function() {
console.log('onAuthRefreshError');
}

keycloak.onAuthLogout = function() {
console.log('onAuthLogout');
}
```

before calling `keycloak.init`:

```
let keycloak = new Keycloak(initOptions);
Vue.prototype.$keycloak = keycloak
console.log(cookies);
window.keycloak = keycloak
const tokenKeycloak = cookies.get('access_token');
const refreshTokenKeycloak = cookies.get('refresh_token');

keycloak.onAuthSuccess = function() {
console.log('onAuthSuccess');
}

keycloak.onAuthRefreshError = function() {
console.log('onAuthRefreshError');
}

keycloak.onAuthLogout = function() {
console.log('onAuthLogout');
}

keycloak.init({
onLoad: initOptions.onLoad,
token: tokenKeycloak,
refreshToken: refreshTokenKeycloak,
checkLoginIframe: false,
enableLogging: true
})
```

It does not work, i. e. I don't see the the output of `onAuthSuccess`, `onAuthRefreshError`, nor `onAuthLogout`.

Comment: I am using keycloak with angular. Trying to get idle session logout event from keycloak. I have different setup, but onAuthRefreshError works for me. However onAuthLogout is not getting called. Not working at session time out nor explicitly ending user session at keycloak. Not sure if it has something to do with Admin URL https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35704546/how-to-use-the-keycloak-admin-url-for-openid-logout-requests